# Have multiple filters for same ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects in an ng-repeat that I am looking to filter.

```
%input{type: 'text', 'ng-show' => "content == 'include'", 'ng-model' => "search.author"}
%input{type: 'text', 'ng-show' => "content == 'exclude'", 'ng-model' => "search.author"}

%tr{'ng-repeat' => 'book in books| filter:search'}
```

The first input filters correctly (filters the authors that match the input string) but for the second input I want to filter the model differently (for example: a filter that [excludes](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/filters/filtering-a-list-of-dom-nodes.html) authors that match the string input).

How would I pass the correct filter from the input to the `ng-repeat` so that it will know how to correctly filter my collection based on what input I am typing from?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom filter on the scope that returns what you want

```
$scope.myFilter = function(item) {
if(content == 'include')
//filter one way
else
//filter another way
};


%tr{'ng-repeat' => 'book in books| filter:myFilter '}
```

Comment: How would the filter be aware of the ng-show value in this case?

Comment: you would make it the if, constraint

Comment: So in this case `include` and `exclude` are not attributes associated with the  author object. They're just arbitrary strings used to identify that I'd like to filter the two otherwise identical inputs differently (so one will filter like `filter:search` and the other will filter like `filter:!search`).